# What is a service provider?

Tags: .net

Sorry if this is a silly question but I am a C developer who just happen to be in a meeting with a bunch of .NET guys and over heard their conversation.

They were sketching out a design and constantly talk of service provider, services and spring. Instead of looking silly by asking them, I just decided to post here.

BTW, I am doing device driver development (have been for more than 10 years using C) and NEVER heard of service provider.

Answer (score 1):

If it was mentioned in the context of Spring, then most likely they were talking about the [Service Locator Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator).

The Service Locator is a concept in Dependency Injection frameworks; it's the "kernel" you can use to obtain abstract services of an arbitrary type.  Usually with some code like this:

```
IMyService myService = locator.GetService<IMyService>();
```

In other words, it provides a special interface for components to gain access to an abstract service - usually an interface type - without knowing anything about the concrete type or how it's instantiated.

Comment: Wow. Seems like C and C# are indeed a world apart :)

Comment: @Joey: Of course.  Even C# and C++ are worlds apart; C# and C are galaxies apart. :P  You'll find Dependency Injection concepts to be more common in managed languages that support Reflection, which is usually a prerequisite.  I don't imagine that it's done too often in C.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, service providers are not at all new to .NET and in fact the IServiceProvider interface was available in COM (good old fashioned unmanaged COM) long before .NET. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678965(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Josh: I was very careful *not* to say that the concept is new to .NET, or to managed languages in general.  Just that it's not *common* in typical Win32 code.  This happens to be possible in COM because of the baked-in GUIDs.